# Проблемы с prepareAsync();

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Пытаюсь воспроизвести музыку из сети. Проблема в том, что программа выбивает ошибку. Методом тыка нашёл, что проблема с mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();. Кто знает как правильно воспроизводить из сети музыку.?

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MyPlayer.getMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(s);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        //if(type==11){mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();}

    }  catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    mediaPlayer.    setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override 
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: если `программа выбивает ошибку`, то вы обязаны прикрепить `stacktrace` этой ошибки

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно из-за `mediaPlayer.reset();` не в том месте. Попробуйте:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ADDRESS_TO_PLAY);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```